# Printf retarget on STM32 with CubeMX

Tags: stm32, c, c++, stm32cubemx

I'm using STM32F7xx for my project where I use VS Code text editor in combination with CMake project build. I also use CubeMX for code generation. For a record I have already examined all the answers in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206113/how-do-i-use-the-printf-function-on-stm32/279945#279945) but none seems to work.

When I generate code using STM32CubeIDE template, the `syscalls.c` file is generated. It provides the following declaration:

```
extern int __io_putchar(int ch) __attribute__((weak));
```

If I provide `__io_putchar()` definition in my `main.cpp` file nothing happens after using `printf()`. However, if I provide `__io_putchar()` function definition inside of `syscalls.c` then `printf()` operates as should and I get output stream printed out on terminal.

```
extern int __io_putchar(int ch) __attribute__((weak));

int __io_putchar(int ch)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_GetHuart3(), (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);
    return ch;
}
```

I have tried several other methods of `printf()` retarget, like retargeting `_write` or `fputc`, however nothing really works besides providing function definition inside of `syscalls.c`. And the problem of providing `__io_putchar()` function definition inside of `syscalls.c` is that after re-generating code from CubeMX, this definition will be removed. Therefore I need more "clean" solution for this.

Comment: I would have expected that the `__attribute__((weak))` should be applied to the function definition. I don't think putting it on the prototype does anything useful. But since it's auto-generated by CubeMX even if you fix it it'll get overwritten then next time you regenerate the project.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something - are you also putting that declaration with the `__attribute__((weak))` in your main.cpp? If you are then that could be what's causing the trouble.

Comment: @brhans The issue was with me not providing `extern "C"` syntax since I was using a C function in C++ file.